# list.addAll() function doesnt work for one list, does work for other succesfully

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-async

My  code;

```
   Future<List<PostModel>> getAutoPost(User user, int count) async {

    List<PostModel> posts = new List<PostModel>();
    //other proces...

    List<PostModel> fromUserPost = await getPostUsers(user, fromUser);
    posts.addAll(fromUserPost);
    List<PostModel> fromGroupPost = await getPostGroups(user, fromGroup);
    posts.addAll(fromGroupPost);

    return posts;
  }
```

[image: Breakpoint result]

As you can see in breakpoint result;

`fromUserPost` and `fromGroupPost` return same,

but `addAll()` function does not  work for `fromUserPost`.

When i clear breakpoint , `posts` return size of same `fromGroupPost`.

What is the reason of this?

Comment: Your breakpoint is on the `posts.addAll(fromGroupPost);` line, so that line hasn't executed yet.

Comment: When i clear breakpoint , ```posts``` return correctly but inside just ```fromGroupPost``` elements , size is 1 (this example) , not 5. https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/11/06/EZoql1.png

Comment: We need to see more code to know where the bug is. My guess is that you have some code elsewhere which clears `posts`, and it happens to happen during the sync call to `getPostGroups`.

Comment: Can you add the function getPostGroups(user, fromGroup) and getPostUsers(user, fromUser) to the question. Maybe something is wrong there.